# C programming problem unrelated variable being overwritten after STRCPY is used

Tags: c, pointers, programming-languages, enums, strcpy

The problem is the variable nodeType is being changed after STRCPY finishes running. nodeType is not a variable that is related to any of the other variables being used in the STRCPY call. It is in the same struct though. nodeType is a enum with the int value of 3.

Below if the following information that is probably most relevant. I removed most of the variables from the enum and struct so they aren't visible, I assume they aren't relevant to the problem. I am coding in VS2010 if that makes a difference. This is part of an assignment to create a btree, but the question I have has nothing to do with btrees.

```
enum NODETYPE
{ 
  ROOTLEAF
};
typedef struct node
{
  char key[MAX_CHILDREN_ROOT][MAX_KEY_LENGTH];
  NODETYPE nodeType;
} nodeT;
```

... part of the insertElement function

```
for (int i = 0; i < (b->tempNode->numberOfKeys - b->searchData.position); i++)
{
  strcpy(b->tempNode->key[b->tempNode->numberOfKeys - i],  b->tempNode->key[b->tempNode->numberOfKeys - (i + 1)]);
}
```

.. the function I called was the to insert an element. I have called the function several times prior to this but this is the first this section of code below is being run. After STRCPY runs nodeType takes the value 1280070990. I set the variable to watch and while its in CXX0017 error, which I assume only means its not in scope.

I looked up the number 1280070990 which spawned a bunch of game related issues from various engines. I'd guess its a memory address problem.

Solution was a provided below. It was a simple error of writing outside of the array boundary. I broke the old code down like this and then walked through it. This allowed me to identify the problem which was me writing outside of the key array key.

```
        for (int i = 0; i < (b->tempNode->numberOfKeys - b->searchData.position); i++)
    {
        int sourceI = b->tempNode->numberOfKeys - i - 2;
        int destI = b->tempNode->numberOfKeys - i - 1;
        char *Source = b->tempNode->key[sourceI];
        char *Dest = b->tempNode->key[destI];
        strcpy(Dest, Source);
    }
```

A full look at the struct that both variables were in.

```
typedef struct node
{
    node *childrenPTR[MAX_CHILDREN_ROOT]; 
    int depth; //Distance from root to node
    char key[MAX_CHILDREN_ROOT][MAX_KEY_LENGTH];
    NODETYPE nodeType;
    int numberOfChildren;
    int numberOfKeys;
    node *parentPTR;
} nodeT;
```

We can see from the order of the variables in the struct that nodeType follows key. I believe C will allocate the memory in this same order. So I could of looked here as well to identify the problem.

Comment: Sounds like your string is overflowing its buffer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're copying a string that's too long into key[] somewhere.  It's overflowing into nodeType.

Since I'm guessing you're new at this, I'd re-code this for a bit easier reading for you to get a handle on what's going on.  Perhaps something like:

```
for (int i = 0; i < (b->tempNode->numberOfKeys - b->searchData.position); i++)
{
  char *dest = b->tempNode->key[b->tempNode->numberOfKeys - i];
  char *source = b->tempNode->key[b->tempNode->numberOfKeys - (i + 1)];
  strcpy(dest, source);
}
```

Walk that through a debugger and `source` will probably be longer than (with the null terminator -- you are null terminating your strings right?) `MAX_KEY_LENGTH` somewhere in your array.  It might even be something crazy not even in your array.

Break it down into something smaller and easier to debug in discreet steps.

Comment: Thanks for help, I've forget sometimes simple trouble shooting steps like breaking it down further to same debugging easier.

Answer (score 2):

This is exactly what happens if you use a str* function, which expects a null terminated string, on something that isn't a null terminated string.  Or if the thing you're copying into isn't big enough for the thing you're copying into it.